# Shortest path in a hypercube graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

A* algorithm is one of the algorithm which produces a shortest path in a given graph.

I am interested in knowing, is there any property of d-dimensional hypercube which allows the parallel computing methods to use the A* on it efficiently. To find the shortest find between the one corner of the hypercube to exactly opposite corner of it. When the edges have certain non-negative weight.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible if you have just any weights, in particular, you could force the algorithm to find exactly one weird path that goes over constant fraction of all the vertices. On the other hand, if you know the weights are in some way uniform, then perhaps you could prioritize vertices that are "in general direction of" the target (i.e. your Hamming distance drops).

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "hypercube" you mean a $d$-dimensional cube, that is, the graph with $2^d$ vertices indexed by length-$d$ bit strings, and edges joining two vertices precisely when their bit strings differ in exactly one bit.

If that's the case, then finding shortest paths in this graph is very simple: if two vertices' bit strings differ in $k$ spots, then just change them one at a time, in any order you like. The resulting list of vertices forms a length-$k$ path between the two vertices, and it's easy to see that this is best possible (using the triangle inequality on Hamming distances, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the input. But what if the edges where weighted